# How to make a File class input case sensitive for the file name?

Tags: java, file, io, case-sensitive

I have a working application here already which reads a text file using the `File` class after prompting the user for the file name input. However, I have to make it case-sensitive which means that say if the user inputs **zombie.txt**, then there will be an `FileNotFoundException` thrown although the actual file name is **Zombie.txt**. So my question is how do I correct my application to make it so?

Additionally, as I'm still a newbie to programming etc, all suggestions or advices to shorten my code will be deeply appreciated. ;)

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class FileReadingExercise {
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileInput = null;
    do {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a file or type QUIT to finish");
            String a = userInput.nextLine();
            if(a.equals("QUIT"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            fileInput = new Scanner(new File(a));                           //inline expression 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error - File does not exist");              //read document as there is more
        }
    }
    while (fileInput == null);
    while(fileInput.hasNext())
    {
        String first  = fileInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println(first);  
    }
    fileInput.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Case-sensitivity is a property of the operating system, not of Java. If you're not running on a case sensitive operating system, the requirement isn't correct: if you are, you don't have to do anything to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Retrieve all fileNames and add them in an `ArrayList`.
2. Use `contains` method of ArrayList for checking user's file name. Contains method is case  sensative.

Comment: Is it ? I doubt - even question says case sensative

Comment: oops.. my bad, +1 (too late here - I better go to bed... :)

Comment: @NinadPingale hey hi Ninad! erm may I ask you how do you actually retrieve all the file names? The file directory can be from anywhere and in my case, mine is on the desktop. Cheers! :)

Comment: Are you accepting complete path or just file name ? - if you are accepting path, you can get parent folder of the file using new File(path).getParentFile(). Once you get parent directory get all files using `file.listFiles()` and get names looping through that list.